# Enable Cython profiling for whole program?

Tags: python, profiling, cython

The Cython docs say "Profiling in Cython is controlled by a compiler directive. It can be set either for an entire file or on a per function basis via a Cython decorator."

Is there any easy way to enable Cython profiling for an entire Python program? That is, is there a way for me to not have to go through and add `# cython: profile=True` to dozens of files each time I want to turn profiling on and off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can set the directives globally by passing an option on the command line to `cython`. It is described in the "Compilation" section of the documentation under "How to set directives" (http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#how-to-set-directives).

> One can also pass a directive on the command line by using the -X switch:
>
> $ cython -X boundscheck=True ...
>
> Directives passed on the command line will override directives set in header comments.

If you are compiling through `distutils` (`setup.py`) and using the `cythonize` function, it appears that you can add the option `compiler_directives`, a dictionary that maps directive names to the corresponding value. I have not found documentation for this feature, but it appears to be how the `cython` program invokes the `cythonize` function (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Build/Cythonize.py#L83).

For example

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = "My hello app",
    ext_modules = cythonize("src/*.pyx",
                            compiler_directives={'profile': True})
)
```

Comment: This compiler_directives option should be documented. It took me way too long to find this.